# Raspberry Pi: No Session for PID 3790

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi 4, running Raspbian 10, that usually stays in console mode where all users except for Pi log in via NIS. Xwindows is generally not needed on this machine but now it is for a specific instance. When I try to access Xwindows via the startx command Xwindows starts but the GUI screen immediately freezes and a window appears which displays the message `ERROR: No session for PID 3790`. Any idea how I can fix this so that Xwindows is accessible for non-pi users?

Comment: Could you add the entire output?

Comment: That is the entire output. After the window displays with that message the Pi freezes and I have unplug it and plug it back in.

Comment: Check the output of `journalctl`, and also look at the contents of the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file. I wonder if you have no window manager installed, is `lightdm` installed?

Comment: Thank you Bid. I ended up doing `apt-get reinstall xorg` and that took care of the problem.